# cp behavior changed. How can old behavior be executed

Tags: cygwin

`cp -rup dir /g/` used to update or create `dir` on `/g/`. A copy or update is now rejected if `/g/` contains `dir/`. I've tried a few options to see if I can create the old behavior and none seem to work.

What I would like is to recursively update all files from an existed directory into a directory with the same name. Don't know how to do it. Does anyone know what command(s) to use?

Comment: What's the exact error you receive?

Comment: ~ >> cp -rup Gnu/ /g/
cp: cannot create directory ‘/g/Gnu’: File exists

Comment: The only way I can get the command to error out is to have Gnu be a file in one tree and a directory in the other. However, I get a different error message saying exactly that. Feels like your trees may be out of sync.